# Launch WebApp in Windows 10 from Docker container inside WSL2 (without Docker for Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have been faced certificate issue using Docker for Windows (With/Without Integration to WSL2). Here is the [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/1587833/docker-containers-facing-curl-60-ssl-certificate-error-after-using-wsl2).

I have installed docker inside WSL2 and Launch VSCode inside the WSL2. everything works fine without issues that I have been faced with Docker for Windows.
The only problem is I have no clue how can I launch WebApp in Windows 10 browser. how can I open the docker port from WSL2 in my Windows 10 browser while I don't have Docker for Windows installed?

I'll appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by Exiting the antivirus. even pausing it didn't helped because the firewall was still active.